# Liferay setup in production

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

We are currently in the process of developing liferay portal web application for our CMS. We are using liferay bundled with tomcat.I have also written some hooks do some customization.
Currently we are at the end of first milestone and thinking of deploying it to pre-prod.

Could anybody please guide me what are the best practices to do this.For e.g. 
1. Should it be single war file containing ROOT and custom hooks?
2. Would the portal-ext be copied as it is ?
3. How would the tomcat be setup ,is it going to be simple unzip of the bundle?

Any link/resource with exact steps to setup production/pre-production server would really help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a deployment checklist for Liferay (EE, but applies to CE as well) in the [whitepaper section on liferay.com](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/additional-resources/whitepapers), with this you'll have a quite good starting point.

If you use the bundle, note that tuning (and maintaining) tomcat is still up to you. The bundles are provided for convenience, not assuming maintenance on Liferay's behalf.

In case you're using Liferay EE (and depending on where in the world you are), you can also get help from Liferay (the company), making sure you'll follow the best practices in deployment.

Edit: You might also want to check my series of blog posts with some (naturally not complete) aspects to take care of when setting up and securing Liferay. [Chapter 1/4 is here](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/securing-liferay-chapter-1-introduction-basics-and-operating-system-level), the other chapters are linked from there.